# Reconciling Quine-McCluskey Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm looking at the [article on wikipdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) for this algorithm, and I see two seemingly contradictory statements:

> "it also gives a deterministic way to check that the minimal form of a Boolean function has been reached"

and

> "has a limited range of use since the problem it solves is NP-hard"

Thoughts?

p.s. Is there a Visual Studio plugin that can reduce conditional logic by applying this algorithtm to highlighted code?

Comment: Don't confuse non-deterministic polynomial *complexity class* with an *algorithm* that is non-deterministic. Two very different things.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm takes exponential time. All NP-complete problems can be solved in exponential time. Presumably the problem referred to is NP-complete in addition to being NP-hard.

The discrepancy is probably because you don't fully understand the definition of NP-hard: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing contradictory in those statements.
You might be confused about what 'deterministic' means in this context:

*In computer science, a deterministic algorithm is an algorithm which, in informal terms, behaves predictably. Given a particular input, it will always produce the same output, and the underlying machine will always pass through the same sequence of states.*

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm)

In this sense, almost all widely used CS algorithms are deterministic.

I'm sure you already know what 'NP-hard' means :)